# Focus on a textarea after custom text on a bootstrap floating modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap to invoke a simple modal form which contains only a textarea field and couple of buttons. I am setting some custom text (variable length) in the textarea while invoking the modal form. What I want is to focus on the textarea field after the custom text so the user can start typing after that. I have mentioned my implemenation of this below. Can anyone tell how to achieve this?

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLymtdg8/

A bit explanation here as well -

Here is my modal (all bootstrap stuff)-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="msg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Type a message</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <textarea id="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button id="PostModalButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is how it gets invoked -

```
<div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#msg" data-screenname="Type after this">
            Post A Message
        </button>
</div>
```

This is how I am prefilling the textarea and setting focus, but this is only setting cursor on first line rather than after screen_name -

```
$(this).on('shown.bs.modal', '#msg', setFieldAndFocus)

var setFieldAndFocus = function () {

    var screen_name = $("button[data-target='#msg']").data("screenname");
    $("#Message").val(screen_name + " ");
    $("#Message").focus();
};
```

Comment: Please provide fiddle for it

Comment: Added the fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam you can try the following javascript code:-

```
    var screen_name = '',
    old_message = '',
    new_message = '';
    $("#msg").on('shown', function() {
        screen_name = $("button[data-target='#msg']").data("screenname"),
        old_message = $.trim($('#Message').val()),
        new_message = ( old_message.length == 0 ) ? screen_name : old_message; 
       $("#Message").focus().val(new_message + " "); 
   });
```

Let me explain why i have used this code. From the js fiddle link that you have provided what i understand is you are using the bootstrap 2 version, but the code that you are using

```
$("#msg").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  ...
}
```

was introduced only in bootstrap 3. so I have changed it to

```
$("#msg").on('shown', function(){
...
}
```

and the line

```
$("#Message").focus().val(new_message + " ");
```

is used so that you can set the focus after the custom text.I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I mistakenly included bootstrap 2 in fiddle but I have used it correctly in my code. I actually tried something similar by myself i.e. setting focus first and then setting the value and it works for me. Just that I am not sure how to do it other way round. Anyways, thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference of this link : http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/433/
It is working for me.

```js
$('.launchConfirm').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#confirm')
        .modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .on('')
        .one('click', '[data-value]', function (e) {
            if($(this).data('value')) {
                //alert('confirmed');
            } else {
                //alert('canceled');
            }
        });
});

$('#confirm').on('shown', function () {
    $('#txtDemo').val($('#txtDemo').val());
    $('#txtDemo').focus();
  // do something…
})
```

```css
body,
.modal-open .page-container,
.modal-open .page-container .navbar-fixed-top,
.modal-open .modal-container {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
 .modal-open .page-container .navbar-fixed-top{
  overflow-y: visible;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <button class="btn launchConfirm">Launch Confirm</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="confirm" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-body">
    Do you want to continue?
      <input id="txtDemo" type="text" value="Jayesh" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="1">Continue</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" data-value="0">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I am pretty much doing the same thing except wiring the click event to launch button (bootstrap takes care of this). Not sure if that is the problem here.

Comment: Click event is listener to buttons in modal, so if you want to eliminate than you can. Please accept answer

Comment: You have only mentioned that some similar code is working fine and not solved my problem.

Comment: Sam you can try my code and see if that resolves your problem.